# A function it Python that replaces strings

Tags: python

I need to write a function, `replaceSegment`, which takes a string, `str`, and another string, `replace`, and two integers, `start` and `stop`.

The function should return a new string in which all occurrences of `'X'` in `str`, ranging from index `start` up to, but not including, the index `stop` are replaced with `replace`.

Built-in functions or modules that perform the same or similar information may not be used in this task.

**Example:**

```
replaceSegment ("HXello! X balXoo!", "Hope", 3, 7) 'HXello! Hope balXoo!
```

It's from an old exam and I can't figure it out. I guess that it should use a for loop?

Comment: "I can't figure it out" it not enough research effort. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Would you know how to do the task without the start and stop arguments?

Comment: Hi there! It would really help your post if you include some attempts that you have already made. Showing the code you are working with (even if it doesn't work), is the **best** way to explain to the community what exactly you are trying to do and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero research effort or attempts and it is unclear where OP is stuck.

Comment: text objects objects support slicing which could help solve your problem: ```'abcdefg'[2:5]``` --> ```cde```.  Have you worked your way through [The  Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you did not post any code, it still seems to me as though you actually did attempt to do this task yourself but you were just really stuck. I decided to help you out here because I see that you're a new member and probably don't know all the rules of the site yet, but in the future, know that people will probably only answer your questions if you include the code you tried:

```
def replaceSegment(s, replace, start, stop):
    new_string = s[:start]
    for c in s[start:stop]:
        new_string += replace if c == 'X' else c
    new_string += s[stop:]
    return new_string
```

Or the equivalent (but disgustingly un-readable) one-liner:

```
replaceSegment=lambda s,r,i,e:s[:i]+''.join(r if c=='X' else c for c in s[i:e])+s[e:]
```

I had to change the name of the first parameter from `str` to `s` because `str` is the name of a built-in function in Python, and it is generally considered poor practice to mask them. Additionally, your example did not really make sense given your algorithm description. I believe the main source of contradiction is that you didn't realize that Python is a zero-indexed language, meaning that the first character of the string has an index of zero, not one. So to get your desired output for the example, I instead called `replaceSegment('HXello! X balXoo!', 'Hope', 2, 9)`. I `replaceSegment('X', 'Hope', 0, 1)` this helps!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've been trying to solve this for a couple of hours and I always get the same error. thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!